# Why won't my elif statement execute but my if statement will in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter, python-2.x

I wrote a simple age verification in python to where if the user enters a year less than 2000, it will say welcome. However, if the user enters a year greater than 2000, it should redirect them to another site.

My code works but only executes only the `if` statement not the `elif` no matter what year I input.

Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import webbrowser
import tkMessageBox


url = 'google.com'
root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
frame.pack()
L1 = Label(root, text = "Month")
L1.pack(side = LEFT)
E1 = Entry(root,bd=5)
E1.pack(side=LEFT)
L2 = Label(root, text = "Day")
L2.pack(side =LEFT)
E2 = Entry(root, bd= 5)
E2.pack(side = LEFT)
L3 = Label(root, text = "Year")
L3.pack(side = LEFT)
E3 = Entry(root, bd = 5)
E3.pack(side = LEFT)

def getdate():
    tkMessageBox.showinfo(title ="Results", message = E1.get() + " "+ E2.get() + " " + E3.get())
    getage()
    root.destroy()
    #tkMessageBox.showinfo(E2.get())
    #tkMessageBox.showinfo(E3.get())
def getage():

    if E3 < 2000:

        tkMessageBox.showinfo(message= "Welcome! ")
    elif E3 > 2000:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo(message="You will be redirected")
        webbrowser.open_new(url)


b1 = Button(root, text = "Submit", width = 25, command = getdate)
b1.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: yes mine is Python 2.7

Answer (score 7):

You are comparing the *`Entry()` object* to an integer. In Python 2, numbers are always sorted *before* other types, so they always register as *smaller*:

```
>>> object() > 2000
True
```

You want to get the value from the entry box and convert to an integer before testing:

```
entry = int(E3.get())
if entry > 2000:
     # ...
else:
     # ...
```

There is no need to do `elif` here, unless you want the value `2000` to be ignored altogether (your test only works for numbers either greater than, or smaller than, not equal).

Answer (score 2):

`Entry` is the object type. You want to call the `get()` function. Like this:

```
EntryBox = Entry(root, bd = 5)
E3 = int(EntryBox.get())
```

Also, note that the `elif` is completely unnecessary. Just use `else` instead.

```
if E3 < 2000:
    tkMessageBox.showinfo(message= "Welcome! ")
else:
    tkMessageBox.showinfo(message="You will be redirected")
    webbrowser.open_new(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You compare an `Entry` object to an `integer`,the `if` statement will never be reached because `integers` are always sorted before `objects`. Look:

```
>>> a = ['0', 9999, {}, [], False, (), object()]
>>> sorted(a)
[False, 9999, {}, [], <object object at 0xb74fa558>, '0', ()]
>>>
```

Use `get` method to get text from `Entry` then convert it with `int`:

```
if int(E3.get()) < 2000:
```

You can use `IntVar()` if you want to get integer from Entry without converting:

```
...
v = IntVar()
E3 = Entry(root, bd = 5, textvariable=v)
...
if E3.get() < 2000:
    tkMessageBox.showinfo(message= "Welcome! ")
else:
    tkMessageBox.showinfo(message="You will be redirected")
    webbrowser.open_new(url)
```